How to restrict past time selection in jquery-clockpicker.min.js
When I am open the clockpicker at that time past time also show, so i want to disabled the past time based on current time.
If my current time is 4:00 PM so inside the clock picker disabled before 4:00 PM time.
I am try this solution but this is not working
This is my HTML code
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.StartTime, new { @class = "form-control clockpicker", autocomplete = "off", @readonly = "readonly", placeholder = "00:00" })

and this is my JS code
var minTime = $("#minTime").val();

    $('.clockpicker').clockpicker({
        donetext: 'Done',
        autoclose: true,
        beforeShow: function () {
            var currentTime = new Date();
            var minHours = currentTime.getHours();
            var minMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
            var minTime = (minHours < 10 ? '0' : '') + minHours + ':' + (minMinutes < 10 ? '0' : '') + minMinutes;

            // Disable times earlier than the current time
            $('.clockpicker-span-hours').each(function () {
                debugger;
                var hour = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
                if (hour < minHours) {
                    $(this).addClass('disabled');
                } else if (hour == minHours) {
                    $('.clockpicker-span-minutes').each(function () {
                        var minute = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
                        if (minute < minMinutes) {
                            $(this).addClass('disabled');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });


According to the library, it seems there is no build-in option to achieve your requirement.  Have you accept the workaround like show error message when the user select the time is before current time?
